# Module#included and Module#extended and Module#prepended comparative discussions

Tags: ruby, module, ruby-2.0

Can anyone help me to understand the below 3 methods about their
functional differences and uses?

> - **Module#included** : *mod.included(other)* is called after *other.include(mod)*
> - **Module#extended** : *mod.extended(obj)* is called after *obj.extend(mod)*
> - **Module#prepended** : *mod.prepended(other)* is called after *other.prepend(mod)*

Can a single example be used to understand the above three comparatively?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In ruby. you can include a module into another class and the methods will be available to instances of that class. Extend is similar, except that the methods get added as class methods to that class. [More info here](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/15/include-vs-extend-in-ruby/) or [here](http://techbot.me/2008/09/including-and-extending-modules-in-ruby/).

[Prepend](http://dev.af83.com/2012/10/19/ruby-2-0-module-prepend.html) is a new 2.0 feature. "sometimes, you want a method from a module to take the precedence on a method from the class. There are some solutions to accomplish this task, like alias_method_chain, but it's more a hack than anything - and not really safe." -- That is, you sometimes want the methods you include be put before the methods inside the class and you can then use `super` to call the original methods inside the class.

Both of these links have detailed examples, so be sure to check those out. But for what is included, prepended and extended used? Well, on the module you want to include/extend/prepend, you can define these functions, and when the actual including/extending/prepending happens, this method will get called with the `obj` parameter being set to the class you are extending. This is useful for instance, when you don't want to add just methods to a class, but want to add stuff like class variables or instance variables to it, or initialize values... endless possibilities.

**Example**

Let's say I have tons of models, like Comment, Post, Picture, etc. Instead of having to copy and paste the same code for implementing a feature like for instance the ability to "like" the thing, I can instead create something like this:

```
module Likable
  def self.included(obj)
    obj.instance_variable_set(:@like_count, 0)
  end
end

class Comment
  include Likable
end

class Picture
  include Likable
end
```

As you can see, this automatically sets a new instance variable called `like_count` to 0. Of course, I'd add more code, but the essence is here, you extract a piece of functionality into a reusable module, which you can then later put into several different classes. This is sometimes used even if you only are adding functionality to a single class, as the advantage of this is that a certain feature is extracted into a separate class and you can understand and tweak the code much easier than if it was mixed with other features.

Answer (score 1):

`Module#prepended` is well described [here](http://blog.crowdint.com/2012/11/05/3-killer-features-that-are-coming-on-ruby-2-0.html) along with another new features in Ruby 2.0

`Module#included` and `Module#extended` work in similar way as `include` and `extend`

Here's a popular pattern that is used in the Rails project:

```
module Talker

  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def say(*args)
      args.each do |arg|
        method_name = ("say_" + arg.to_s).to_sym
        send :define_method, method_name do
          puts arg
        end
      end
    end
  end

end
```

`included` is hook on `include` event (same as `extended` on `extend`), it invokes when module `Talker` is included into another class.

By this functionality we can extend the original class instead of this pattern:

```
class Original
  include Talker
  extend Talker::ClassMethods
  ...
end
```

Comment: You did a lots.. but for my thick brain, just would like to request you, can the three concept be explained with a single example comparatively? :)